# Cannot find Android app in the play store

Tags: discussion, android-app

I cannot find the Stack Exchange Android app in the Android play store when I search for it. The link provided [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/) is no longer valid. Has this app been discontinued? If not, when will it be back? Is there another alternative?

Comment: The [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow&utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=gen-so-mobile-app&utm_content=blog-link&utm_term=app-launch) redirect from the blog is not working either. Seems it is off the store

Comment: Searching the play store I can only see a Stack Exchange beta version, but it says "you're a beta tester for this app" so it must just be an old one I signed up for years ago, I couldn't see anything public.